# how do i call for a vaiable using user_input

Tags: lua, user-input

the file im working on is a feckin mess so im going to use this instead

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
user_input =
```

I want to be able to write b in the terminal and get back 2
ive tried all the different io functions and I don't want to use print
… sorry if this is stupid simple im a new programmer (learning)
also please don't out right tell me how to solve this problem just get me on the right track please

Comment: You should include what you have tried in your question, always show your effort you have put into trying to solve your problem. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to output something based on the user input you could instead make a table like

```lua
values = {
['a'] = 1,
['b'] = 2,
['c'] = 3,
--continued for as many as you want
}
```

and then simply print the value at the index they input

```lua
if values[user_input] then --Make sure the index is valid before trying to print it
    print(values[user_input]) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is:

```
if (user_input=="b"){
print(b)
}
```

Comment: the script I plan on using this info on is around 700 lines long will I have to put that in every line?

Comment: Are you saying you have 700 variables like "a", "b", "c"....if yes, then yes you have to. you can also use case/switch statements or any version of that.

Comment: There is no case/switch statement in lua. Also the code in your answer is not valid in lua.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use globals `a`, `b` and `c`, you can refer to them as `_G[var]`:

```lua
var = io.read()
print _G[var]
```

Also, you can use `getfenv()`/`setfenv()` in Lua 5.1 and `_ENV` in Lua 5.2+ to avoid polluting the global scope (see http://lua-users.org/wiki/EnvironmentsTutorial).

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local table = {}
table .a = 1
table .b = 2
table .c = 3

local function test_inclusion()
    io .write( 'key: ' )
    key = io .read()

    if table[ key ] then
        value = table[ key ]
        io .write( 'value: ' ..value ..'\n' )
    end
end

test_inclusion()
```